# Remove /web/site-name from URL liferay

Tags: java, url, liferay, portlet, friendly-url

I Created one Friendly URL in my project. The URL is like " http://localhost:8080/web/site-name/shareprofile/-/m/pf??OTE="

```
Here I want to remove /web/sitename/ from this URL programitically.
```

Please can any one help me for this solution?

Thanks

Comment: `String#replace("/web/site-name", "")` can be used. But why?

Answer (score 3):

Configure a Virtual Host name in the site settings for the public pages of that site. If you set it to `www.example.com`, you'll be able to reach the page by omitting the `/web/site-name` part from the URL, but you'll have to come through that host name - it will now determine which site you want to visit, replacing the `/web/site-name` selector.